# How to use saved image in pycharm as a pygame image

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a game in pygame with pycharm. I have added a image file to the project folder of the game, but cannot access the file. The file is in the same directory but IDK how to tell pygame to use it. 
Heres the code:

```
import pygame 
import random
import os

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
FPS = 30

game_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
img = os.path.join(game_folder, "img")

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.(os.path.join(img)).convert()[enter image
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your passing in the right path? Shouldn't `"img"` be something like `"img.png"` or `"img.jpeg"`?

Comment: hmm maube not. I saved the image under the same directory as the game /projectfiles so do I even need the import os?

Comment: It also tells me theres a syntax error in the (os.path.join(img)).convert() part saying the the first ( is the error                   ^

Comment: The name of the function is [pygame.image.load](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load). If the file is in the same folder as your .py file, you can omit the `os.path` stuff: `self.image = pygame.image.load('img.png').convert()` should work if the name of the file is 'img.png'.

Comment: or `p1_jump.png` as the image name should work.

Comment: Hey it worked! Thank you man. Any tutorials you know of that better teach file paths for python? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can use almost any type of image file in your game, but it’s easiest
if you use a bitmap (.bmp) file because Pygame loads bitmaps by default.
Although you can configure Pygame to use other file types, some file types
depend on certain image libraries that must be installed on your computer.
(Most images you’ll find are in .jpg, .png, or .gif formats, but you can convert
them to bitmaps using tools like Photoshop, GIMP, and Paint.)